# Can't use scanf in variable 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have an assignment which requires me to make a N*N array then fill the array with numbers from 1 to N^2. After that I have to check if the array is a magic cube, but this is not my problem. I've tried everything but I can't fill the array; scanf keeps going forever.

As you can see in the screenshot, in the first scanf, let's say I press 2 and enter, the variable n becomes 2, so an array named msquare[2][2] has to be created. But when it comes to the second scanf something doesn't work right and it lets me type forever. I would really appreciate some help. Also, if the problem has to do something with pointers please try to explain as good as you can because I'm still not familiar with them and can't understand them perfectly.

Here's an example :

```
int n;
int i;
int j;

scanf("%d", &n);

int msquare[n][n];   

for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=n; j++){
            scanf("%d",msquare[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please copy the code here and post a minimal executable example. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Show text instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post code as text in the question itself. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: At least `scanf("%d", msquare[i][j])` -> `scanf("%d", &msquare[i][j])`. But there may be more problems in the code you didn't show.

Comment: Note that idiomatic `for` loops in C are of the form `for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++)`. (You can omit the `int` if you need the variable outside the loop and define the variable beforehand.) If you fixed the `scanf()` problem, your loops using `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` would write outside the bounds of the array, wreaking havoc on your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's three issues that need to be addressed in your code.

The first one is that you can't create arrays based on *uninitialized* variables!

For example, you can't do this:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    int m[n][n];
    return 0;
}
```

Just make sure you initialize the variable before the array declaration, like this:

```
int main() {
    int n = 2;
    int m[n][n];
    return 0;
}
```

Since you're getting the value of `n` from a `scanf` call, you could simply write this:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int m[n][n];
    return 0;
}
```

But you might run into trouble if `scanf` fails for some reason.
The proper way to handle this is to check the value of `scanf`.

```
int main() {

    int n;

    if (sscanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Failed to get a matrix size from stdin\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int m[n][n];

    return 0;
}
```

And it's sometimes a good idea to initialize your variables to a sensible value.
In this case, 0 would be a good choice.

```
int main() {

    int n = 0;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Failed to get matrix size!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int m[n][n];

    return 0;
}
```

While there's some cases that it's useful to leave variables uninitialized, it's beyond the scope of this answer.

It might be a good idea at this point to add a check to ensure your first input variable does not exceed the value of 8.

The second issue is your for loops.

You're looping one extra iteration that you should be doing.

For example, this code:

```
int n = 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; n++) {
  printf("i = %d and n = %d\n");
}
```

Prints:

```
0 2
1 2
2 2
```

See how it goes three times instead of 2? You should be using the `<` operator instead of the `<=` operator to fix this issue.

Your loops (both of them) should end up looking something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    }
}
```

And the last issue is in your second call to `scanf`. This function accepts a pointer (as you did in your first call) but you're passing it an integer instead in your second call.

```
scanf("%d", m[i][j]);
```

You need to add the `&` to make it a pointer.

```
scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
```

Fix those things and your code should run okay.

Comment: `int m[n][n];` is called a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and was introduced in C99, however in C11 was made an optional feature. MS Visual C has never supported it, but plainly OP's compiler allows it.

Comment: Ah, I always thought it was a compiler extension and not part of the standard.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did everything that you mention and for some reason I still have the exact same problem as before

Comment: @WeatherVane fixed.

Comment: @Thanos can you post an update on the code you're using that's still causing the issue?

Comment: @tay10r it seems that it works now, i forgot to change the = at j<=n. Thank you so much for helping me and thank you to everyone else !

Comment: The initialization in `int n = 2;
    scanf("%d", &n);` is almost pointless.  To the extent it is not pointless, it means that if the `scanf()` call fails to read a value (returns either 0 or EOF), then `n` still has a known value (`2`).  But that's very subtle and should be commented upon, and to be sensible you'd also have to deal similarly with the other `scanf()` — and you don't show that.  It would be better to check the return value from `scanf()` and abandon ship if the value returned is not `1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I think it would be sensible to either initialize n to zero or to just check the return value of scanf. I'll give that an update.

Answer (score 2):

Note that idiomatic `for` loops in C are of the form

```
for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++)
```

(You can omit the `int` if you need the variable outside the loop and define the variable beforehand.)

Some versions of the question had `scanf("%d", msquare[i][j]);` without an `&`, and some versions had `scanf("%d", &msquare[i][j]);`.  The version with the `&` is correct.

With the `scanf()` problem fixed, your loops using

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

lead the code to access outside the bounds of the array, wreaking havoc on your program.  Remember: if you declare an array `msquare[5][5]`, then you can access elements `msquare[0][0]` through `msquare[4][4]` — any larger indexes than `4` (or negative indexes) access the array out of bounds.  Since you define `msquare[n][n]`, you mustn't use anything bigger than `msquare[n-1][n-1]`, but your loop controls mean you try to access `msquare[n][n]` (written as `msquare[i][j]`, but accessing out of bounds when `i == n || j == n`).

You're invoking undefined behaviour, so anything is possible.  One of the many possibilities is that you overwrite the value of `n` with one of your inputs, so instead of being `2` it becomes `38` or whatever you entered, whereupon your loop takes a lot longer than you expected.  No-one can be certain that's what's happening — undefined behaviour can do anything.  But it is a semi-plausible explanation.

Comment: thanks for relplying, could you please explain to me how my loops are writing outside the bounds of the array? I read your explanation but still can't figure out whats wrong

Comment: @Thanos Supoose you have 3 drawers numbered from 0 to 2. What happens if you try to put something into drawer number 3?

Comment: Suppose you enter `8` for `n`. The array can be indexed from `0` to `7`, but your loops index it from `0` to `8`. There is *no* element `[8]`.